# Magic Mouse 2 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, bluetooth, apple

I'm trying to get the magic mouse 2 scrolling setup on Ubuntu 20.04.
I've followed the instructions from the Github driver page - https://github.com/rohitpid/Linux-Magic-Trackpad-2-Driver and this great blog post on tuning the variables http://sneclacson.blogspot.com/2016/09/using-apple-magic-mouse-with-ubuntu-1604.html

I understand these were based on 16.04 which relied on Xorg and since 18 this has moved to Wayland so it's not 100% applicable to this scenario.

I've got scrolling working but i'm unable to make it persistent across reboots. Everytime I restart I need to unload/load the hid_magicmouse module to get it working again.

I created a service to run a script that does this automatically after the user session has loaded but this doesn't appear to be work (I'm guessing it's still executing prior to the mouse connecting):

```
cat mouse.service 

[Unit]
Description=mouse scroll
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/Scripts/mouse.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
cat /Scripts/mouse.sh 
#!/bin/sh
rmmod hid_magicmouse
modprobe hid_magicmouse
```

Is there a simple way to run this script/service as root when a user logs in given the mouse connects prior to a user logging in?

Comment: This question could be asked in the AskUbuntu forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, via a 3 step process:

First, read `man sudoers sudo`, and set up passwordless `sudo` access to `rmmod` and `modprobe` for that particular user..

Second, write a `bash` script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
sudo rmmod hid_magicmouse
sudo modprobe hid_magicmouse
exit 0
```

Finally, invoke the script at (GUI) `login` time by putting a `magicmouse.desktop` file in `$HOME/.config/autostart/`.

Use `locate .desktop` to find many examples of `.desktop` files.

Comment: Thanks, that's working now! I've also learned about visudo and locate as part of this answer.